# Calling javascript function from Java in Play Framework 2

Tags: java, javascript, backbone.js, playframework-2.0

I'm making a little messaging aggregation app in Play Framework 2, and basically what it does is :

- A python script gets data from the web, basically just text.
- It send the data to a route in the Play Framework 2 app via POST
- Then, this message gets stored in the database

Now what I want to do, is display these messages in real time as they get added to the database.
I have some kind of newsfeed page which works like this :
When you manually add a message, all the users get notified of the message and see it in real time.

But when a message gets added via this route, I don't know how to display it in real time on the newsfeed. I always have to refresh to see it.

I'm using backbone.js as an MVC for the viewing part, so I wondered if there is a way of calling my "render" function from within Application.java ? Or should I consider working around with websockets ?

I'm really confused with all this, so any help would be nice.

Comment: Did you had a look at the LiveClock sample? https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/samples/java/comet-clock/app/controllers/Application.java

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'm reading it now but I'm not a real pro, I'm learning. Any hint on how this can help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot call render from Application.java. You should use comet or websockets.

One option is to use an actor keep track of all open user connections (comet or websocket). Add a new connection to a collection when a new browser connects.

When a message is added to the database, send this actor a message.

When the actor receives a message broadcast to all open connections.

On the client side, you can update your model on message, which would automatically update your view.

The [LiveClock](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/samples/java/comet-clock/app/controllers/Application.java) example is a good one to follow. You can use websockets just as easily too.